# `?` placeholder for SQL `IN` condition with persistent's `rawSql`

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, persistent, rawsql

I would be happy to use `?` placeholder to populate ids for SQL `IN` clause.  Unfortunately the following does not work

```hs
let idList :: [ RequestId ]
    idList = []
let sql :: String
    sql =  "SELECT ?? FROM request WHERE request.id IN ?"
rs <- runDB $ rawSql sql [ toPersistValue idList ]
```

Such code results in database error similar to:

```
syntax error at or near "'[283,282,281]'"
```

Wrapping `?` placeholder with brackets (e.g. `IN (?)`) gives another type of error:

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "[283,282,281]"
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

*P.S. Looks like it's a horrible title, have no idea how to improve that*

Comment: What is `??` doing here?

Comment: It allows to convert resulting data into Entity value on the fly

Comment: What if you use `... IN (?)` (so with parenthesis)?

Comment: Typically however you can use more advanced functions for such requests, like `selectList [RequestId <-. []] []`. This will construct the query for you, and make sure it is converted to the proper entities.

Comment: Dear Willem, I have to use `rawSql` because I have to join 3 tables in real code.  In past I'd use `esqueleto`, but since I use latest LTS Stackage it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it with `persistent`.
`postrgresql-simple` (assuming that we are talking about Postgres here) which is used by `persistent` does have special [In](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Types.html#t:In) construct which is correctly translated into [In (..)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6/docs/src/Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField.html#line-108) in SQL, but `persistent` doesn't seem to use it.
One may hope that a workaround is to use [PersistDbSpecific](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.8.2/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#v:PersistDbSpecific) constructor which takes `ByteString` as an argument (so we could manually render and pass something like `(123,456,789)`) but unfortunately it is converted into SQL via [Unknown](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/b26c43318047ed94b707404a7e1f219f79c67d70/persistent-postgresql/Database/Persist/Postgresql.hs#L436) which is then rendered via [Escape](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/b26c43318047ed94b707404a7e1f219f79c67d70/persistent-postgresql/Database/Persist/Postgresql.hs#L450) which not only escapes the string but also [encloses it into quotes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToField.html#v:Escape) which makes our SQL invalid. If `persistent` were using [Plain](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToField.html#v:Plain) (which in my view would make much more sence) this approach would work, but unfortunately it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not use `IN`, but the more flexible `ANY` function:

```
let idList :: [ RequestId ]
    idList = []
let sql :: String
    sql =  "SELECT ?? FROM request WHERE request.id = ANY(?)"
rs <- runDB $ rawSql sql [ PersistArray (map toPersistValue idList) ]
```

(`PersistArray` makes sure persistent renders the list using array literals. `toPersistValue` alone gives a syntax error).

You can read more about the syntax at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparisons.html (look at the `ANY/SOME (array)` section).